# Migrating From Django to Pyramid

Tags: python, django, mongodb, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have created an online webstore. Initially I used Django due to its awesome ORM (in fact the first ORM I met) and built-in admin.

My webstore consists of couple basic components such as shopping cart, a catalog and some user management module.

Over the time I realized that using the built-in admin is not efficient. I spent a lot of time reworking the data registration form due to FK relationship tables and as the items in the webstore diversified, the catalog table has to be extended.

One of the solution that came across my mind is to develop the catalog using NoSQL such as MongoDB in order to make it more flexible. A great idea but then I found out that NoSQL is not officially supported in Django. There is a fork of Django that supports NoSQL but the version is way behind the mainstream and there is no guarantee will be supported for a long time.

Then I came across Pyramid. I really love Python and I would like to stay developing using it. I found out that Pyramid has SQLAlchemy to replace the Django ORM and can be used with MongoDB. It also simpler; I have to plug only components that I want to use and there is lesser point of sticking with Django as I found out the built in admin is not practical for this.

However, I have yet found any good Pyramid hosting. Should I migrate my webstore to Pyramid? Does it worth it? What are the risk and challenges that I need to consider before this migration?

Comment: You can use NoSQL in Django. If you want to use `MongoDB`, try [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) or [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/)

Comment: @PuffinGDI Yes, but it wont be treated as ORM will it? Did you find it easier ?

Comment: pyramid can be hosted anywhere that can host python wsgi applications. webfaction.com is one such host but there are plenty of others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/) is very similar to the ORM used by Django.

Sample code:

**Model:**

```
class UserProfile(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User, required=True, primary_key=True)
    name = StringField()
```

**View or Action**

```
user_obj = authenticate(username=account, password=passwd)
profile_obj = UserProfile.objects(user = user_obj).first()
profile_obj.name = "Mongo"
profile_obj.save()
```

Comment: are you suggesting using mongoengine with Pyramid or Django ?

Comment: mongoengine doesn't support Pyramid now. It only supports Django and Flask. If you really want to use Pyramid, your best option is probably to write your code to interact directly with NoSQL DB.

Comment: mongoengine works just fine with pyramid

Comment: why the heck is it being hold? I cant understand .. of course, we are asking about opinion that could be based on some solutions.